# Deep copy looses content in vue

Tags: vue.js, deep-copy

I'm having trouble with the code below. I'm not sure why by clearing the variable `this.childrenCategories` to `[]` makes the deep copy of it, `childrenCategories1`,also loose its list content. The problem is within the last if statement. Code is shown below:

```
data () {
    return {
      categoryOptions: [],
      categoryCodeMap: {},
      childrenCategories: []
    }
  }


categoryList2(groupedCategories,categoryLabel,topLevelParent) {
      var childrenCategories1 = []
      var breadthTarget = groupedCategories.length
      
      groupedCategories.sort((categoryA, categoryB) => categoryA.category_title.localeCompare(categoryB.category_title))
      for (var i = 0; i < breadthTarget; i++) {
        this.childrenCategories.push(groupedCategories[i].category_title)
        this.categoryCodeMap[groupedCategories[i].category_title] = groupedCategories[i].category_code
        if (groupedCategories[i].children.length > 0) {
          this.categoryList2(groupedCategories[i].children)
        }
        if (topLevelParent) {
          categoryLabel = groupedCategories[i].category_title
          // childrenCategories1 = Object.assign(this.childrenCategories)
          childrenCategories1 = cloneDeep(this.childrenCategories)
          console.log(childrenCategories1 == this.childrenCategories)
          console.log(childrenCategories1 === this.childrenCategories)
          console.log("@@@",childrenCategories1)
          console.log("###",this.childrenCategories)
          this.categoryOptions.push({'label':categoryLabel,'options':childrenCategories1})
        }
        this.childrenCategories = []
      }
    }
```

`console.log(childrenCategories1 === this.childrenCategories)` returns `false` but by adding `this.childrenCategories = []` both `childrenCategories1` and  `this.childrenCategories` become empty.

Why is that the case, have I not already made a deepcopy of the object with `childrenCategories1 = cloneDeep(this.childrenCategories)`? What do I need to do such that `this.childrenCategories = []` does not clear `childrenCategories1`?

Comment: Sounds like a problem in `cloneDeep`. Can you show that method?

Comment: ```cloneDeep``` comes from a javascript library. I've tried using ```Object.assign(this.childrenCategories)``` which didn't help either.